# Am I able to load information from another page in my website with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a mock shopping website for my portfolio, and I'd like the home page to automatically show the first items posted on the shopping page of the website. Is there a way I can use Javascript to load the image, title, and price written on another page, and put it on the home screen?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this, but we probably need more information about your website to answer. Was this created by a web developer (do you have full access to the code), was this created through a simplified editor as Wordpress? When I think about your issue, I would probably load the products information from the database, and display them with PHP.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program to take the web page content and then clean the HTML to get the content you need. An example is [cors-anywhere with NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere).

If you can only do it on the frontend (like you use [Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/making-http-requests/)), you can call [this API](https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=https://google.com) to get the website content. But this method is not recommended because the above website may stop working at any time. So you should create it for yourself.